# Symfony2. How to save request body from 400: Invalid json message received

Tags: php, json, symfony

I'm writing a web API.

I'm working with an 3rd party client that has sent a `application/json` request with an invalid JSON body.

My controller never get's the request because Symfony responds with `Invalid json message received (400 Bad Request)`.

The developer of the 3rd party client will need this invalid JSON to debug their software.

Other than changing the content-type to `text/plain`, then testing the JSON myself, how can I save the invalid JSON for review later?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to log an exception during a request handle, you just need to register an event listener on the `kernel.exception`. This event dispatches a `GetResponseForExceptionEvent` where you can find the triggered exception, the request and some others informations.

So, in this listener, check if the exception if a `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\BadRequestHttpException` and then, log the request body where/as you want for further debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, ok.  This was programmer error.  The check wasn't done by Synfony, but by a leftover Friends Of Symfony Rest module.  After removing this module, the behavior disappeared.  Controller has to check the JSON body anyways.